# Determine if base class subroutine has been overridden from the base class

Tags: perl, inheritance

This question had stumped me but I have since solved the problem and will post my answer.

I have a base class called `Parent`

#### Parent

```
package Parent;

sub new {
    my $c = shift;
    my $s = {}, bless $s, $c;
    return $s;
}

sub who {
    return "parent";
}

1;
```

This parent class exposes a single method; `who`.

I wrote two child classes: `Child` and `Freak`. Only `Child` overrides `who`.

#### Child

```
package Child;

use base 'Parent';

sub who {
    return "child";
}

1;
```

#### Freak

```
package Freak;

use base 'Parent';

1;
```

How can the base class determine whether the base `who` method has been overridden?

I want to be able to write something like this

```
package Parent;

sub new {
    my $c = shift;
    my $s = {}, bless $s, $c;
    return $s;
}

sub who {
    return "parent";
}

sub check {
  my $self = shift;

  my $is_overridden = 1; # what conditional should be here?

  return $is_overridden ? "yes" : "no";
}

1;
```

What conditional can I use to determine if the subroutine is overridden?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why are you using `my $s = {}, bless $s, $c;`? There's no need for that first comma and it should be a semicolon. As it is, your code will fail at compile time or run time, depending on whether you have `use strict` in place as you should.

Comment: To further what @Borodin said, if you're not going to modify the object in the instantiation method, you can simplify: `return bless {}, shift;`

Comment: @stevieb: It's not often the best idea to contract code into as short a space as possible. It is the compiler's job to optimise your code, and your job to use the language to make your solution as readable as possible. `shift` means nothing, and `my $self = shift` or (for a class method) `my $class = shift` makes the ensuing code much more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my $is_overridden = $self->can("who") != Parent->can("who");
```

See the documentation for the [`UNIVERSAL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL) package, which defines `can`.

Also, I should add on a more philosophical note - it sounds like your overriding is violating the [Liskov Subsitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), it would probably be better to refactor things so that overriding a method isn't something you have to investigate elsewhere in the code.

Comment: That's an intelligent answer, but it's only small or idealised problems that lend themselves to "proper" object-oriented programming. Most solutions will require either fumbles like this or multiple "glue" classes that exist only to provide for the rules of object-orientation.

Comment: I've not yet seen an example of where it was justified for a base class to vary its behaviour based on what the child class does. Presumably the purpose of a base class is to manifest the invariance between a collection of subtypes in a reusable manner. This is kind of code effectively makes that class closed for extension - it can no longer be safely subclassed or its subclasses refactored, so it increases the likelihood of not being able to articulate an ontology for the problem with the atoms of OO modeling, as it further detracts from the already sketchy inheritance mechanism's usefulness.

Comment: I should clarify, it's not that it's closed for extension per se, it's more that it's potentially so, it's just that there are additional constraints on what subclassing means that are orthogonal to the built in concepts of inheritance - so more things to consider and get confused about when using this class as a base class.

Comment: I agree that this is probably a poor solution to whatever the underlying problem may be—it's not much of a jump from this to testing the calling object's class to determine the base class's behaviour—but a rigorous object-oriented design will often make the code unnecessarily complex (just  look at Java) and is particularly prone to requiring massive changes for even small modifications.

Comment: Well, FWIW, needing to violate LSP is a design smell.  And as nothingmuch noted, violating it comes at a cost.  So if you find yourself in a situation where this seems like a good idea, it's time to take a step back and see if you can partition your problem differently.

Comment: **Everyone please stop abusing the comments.** I have cleaned up a lot of junk here, almost all of it inappropriate. Please read the ["Be Nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy and refrain from further comments about other users.

Answer (score 4):

```
Parent->UNIVERSAL::can('who') ne Child->UNIVERSAL::can('who')
```

`UNIVERSAL::can(PACKAGE,METHODNAME)` returns a reference to the subroutine that will be called when the given method name in used in the given package. If the packages are different but the return values are the same, it means that one package is inheriting the method from the other (or they are both inheriting it from a common source). This method works for multiple levels of inheritance:

```
package Parent;
sub foo { 42 }
sub bar { 19 }
sub baz { 47 }

package Child;
@Child::ISA = qw(Parent);
sub bar { 19 }

package Grandchild;
@Grandchild::ISA = qw(Child);
sub foo { 42 }

##############

package main;

print "foo:", Parent->UNIVERSAL::can('foo'), 
    Child->UNIVERSAL::can('foo'),
    Grandchild->UNIVERSAL::can('foo'),"\n";

print "bar:", Parent->UNIVERSAL::can('bar'), 
    Child->UNIVERSAL::can('bar'),
    Grandchild->UNIVERSAL::can('bar'),"\n";

print "baz:", Parent->UNIVERSAL::can('baz'), 
    Child->UNIVERSAL::can('baz'),
    Grandchild->UNIVERSAL::can('baz'),"\n";
```

Typical output:

```
foo:CODE(0x17e26e8)CODE(0x17e26e8)CODE(0x17e2b38)
bar:CODE(0x17e27a8)CODE(0x17e29b8)CODE(0x17e29b8)
baz:CODE(0x17e2850)CODE(0x17e2850)CODE(0x17e2850)
```

Comment: `==` is more efficient than `eq`for references.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this dilemma is as follows:

The existence of methods within packages can be determined by statically checking its CODE reference like so:

```
if( defined &Child::who ){
  return "yes";
}
```

But since the parent can be overridden by many, many different children, and I don't want to manually refer to all of them, I'll get the reference to the package (which will be the package name in string form) and evaluate it.

```
sub check {
  my $self = shift;
  my $package = ref $self; # 'Freak' or 'Child', etc.

  my $is_overridden = eval "defined &".$package."::who";
  die "eval error occurred" if $@;

  return $is_overridden ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

And there you have it!

Comment: Rather than that horrible `eval`, you could have written `exists &{"${package}::who"}`